# Inner shadow only from one side with blur

Tags: html, css

how I can make **inner shadow** only from one side in `div` with blurring? When I use `blur` the shadow is on another sides.
I'm trying to use that in *infotextgorny* `div` on http://inter-dom.com.pl/?page_id=14

Comment: Welcome! Do not make people go to your site and dig for your problem. Put the offending and *specific* parts of your markup/css that are causing your problem in the question. Preferably as well, make a http://jsfiddle.net *in addition to this* as a demonstration. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `:before` or `:after` pseudo-selectors: size and position them, after apply required effects on them. So, in this way you can still use your main div's styles w/o blur or whatever you need.

Comment: Can you make an example with my page?

Comment: Once you create an example on [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net), it would be easier for everybody.

Comment: Great, thanks, but there's problem - on Opera the shadow haves poor darker places on left and right sides. How to fix it?